# Как задать условие WHERE в методе update при работе с базой данных?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Как правильно записывается условие обновления в таблицу базы данных, если
при проверке этого условия сверяется две ячейки таблицы:

```
mDataBase.update(
    MyTable.NAME, contentValues, MyTable.Cols.ITEM_1 && MyTable.Cols.ITEM_2 + " =? ", 
    new String[]{item1, item2});
```

Как правильно указать третий и четвертый аргументы в методе `update`?

Comment: Попробуйте третий `MyTable.Cols.ITEM_1 + " =? and " + MyTable.Cols.ITEM_2  + " =?"`. С четвёртым всё ок.

Comment: спасибо, проверю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
database.update(MyTable.NAME, contentValues, MyTable.Cols.ITEM_1 + "=? and " +  MyTable.Cols.ITEM_2 + "=?", new String[] {item1, item2});
```

Comment: спасибо, вечером протестирую...